# Firebase Cloud Messages with Analytics and user properties

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I'm using `Firebase Analytics` and `User Properties` in my app to collect some data and to see how the users are using the app etc.

My app has both `Free Version` and `Pro version`. Before hire the Pro version, the user can use the Pro Version as a `Trial of 1 month`. When the user starts the Free Trial, I'm creating a event named **"started_free_trial"** and with this event I'm sending a **"created_at"** event attribute equal to `System.currentTimeInMillis()`.

Now I want to send the cloud notifications from the Firebase console to the users who are using the trial period of Pro version at intervals of 15 days, 25 days and 30 days from the free trial start.

So here are the points what i want to do exactly

1. Create a Audience of users who started the Trial 15, 25 and 30 days ago. Can I do that? As Firebase provides an option to create audiences but I don't know how to create such type of audience to filter according to my requirement.
2. I want to send notification to that above created audiences.

I need your help to complete/perform above 2 points.

Looking for positive response.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't really create an audience based on time the user started using your app, since the audiences are sticky, once a user is in the audience she will remain there forever.

However, instead of targeting to an audience, you can use user property directly to target your notification to users that registered after certain time or before certain time.

Just make you app to store the first start time to user property and the use that as the condition. You can also create other relatewd conditions and combine them.